# How does interpreter.run(input, output) work? What is the output and how to process the output to print the label with the highest accuracy

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, inference

I learned how to use an interpreter by following this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) and saw the code to run Inference:

```
try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(file_of_a_tensorflowlite_model)) {
  interpreter.run(input, output);
}
```

I have found an example using the interpreter by TensorFlow: [gesture_classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/gesture_classification/android) but still, I don't know what is their `labelProbArray` and how to process to print the label with highest confidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `labelProbArray` in the gesture classification example is initialized as a 1-D array (technically, a 2-D array with the first dimension of length 1) as shown in [ImageClassifierFloatInception.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/gesture_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/gesture/ImageClassifierFloatInception.java#L45) of gesture classification example. Its length equals to the number of labels, so each value in the array represents the probability that the current data is associated with that specific label. For example, if `labelProbArray = new float[][]{{0.6, 0.3, 0.1}};`, then the probability that the current data is gesture label 0 is 60%, the probability that the current data is gesture 1 is 30%, and so on. If you find the array index with the largest probability value and print out, then that's the label with the highest confidence.

Meanwhile, a better example to understand how `interpreter.run(input, output)` works is [model_personalization](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/model_personalization). The interpreter invocation shown in the [LiteMultipleSignatureModel.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/model_personalization/android/transfer_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/transfer/api/LiteMultipleSignatureModel.java) file is directly matched with the function signature defined in the [Python model](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/model_personalization/transfer_learning/generate_training_model.py).